# Desktop build for 3 or 4 monitors

Tags: graphics-cards, desktop, displays

I'm quite new to pc building. I'd like to seek advises about building a computer which can support up to 3 or 4 monitors, and as cheap as possible.
I went to few pc shops, some recommend me to get GTX 1050ti while others recommend me to get GTX1060. So i'm confused now.

Purpose of the computer
 - Screen 1 for main screen controls (Monitor)
 - Screen 2 to display videos or image etc (Projector)
 - Screen 3 to display theme text or title (Monitor)
 - Screen 4 backup  (Monitor)
*All displays will be in HD (1080).*

Requirement
 - Build based on Intel Processor
 - Both Nvidia and AMD graphic are acceptable as long as it can support the function mentioned above (as well as other parts; Motherboard, ram etc.)

Please let me know if you need further details.

Comment: technically both types of card can do the job, the more interesting question is whether any concrete model has the right number of ports (which will usually be 3x DisplayPort + 1x HDMI).

Comment: @SEJPM Thanks. How about combine the ports on motherboard with the ports on gpu? Will that work?

Comment: If you plug into the integrated GPU (motherboard DVI output), you likely won't be able to use the discreet GPU as well. Best bet is to just daisy-chain the DisplayPort connection.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks. I'll look into it. I just realized that i didn't mention that one of the display will be a projector.